# Mobile Application in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flashlite

Just to be clear ,this is a university project that i am doing ,this is my first time working with flash/AS.i am half way implementing the mobile web application.I have used Flash Lite 4 and Actionscript 3. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Lite
"Adobe Flash Lite 4 has been released (2010) and integrated in Symbian^3 (Nokia N8, Nokia E7...)"-wikipedia
The problem is only a no of devices are currently supporting Flash Lite v4.my question is would older models able to render it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends! if you are using Flash Lite 4 specific features, it won't run on earlier devices.
Not clear from your question, if you are concerned about specific APIs/features.

I would advise to compare Flashlit 4 API and previous versions:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/43ca0681-c8c6-4684-ad71-c4ac41f3ee4f/Flash_Lite_Developers_Library.html

Also check if the SDK supports full-backwards compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Flash, especially FlashLite, is only supported on a very limited selection of devices. The very fact that Adobe does not make a big show of what devices actually support it should give you an indication of its adoption rate.

Apart from hardware capabilities, there are also limitations on a per device basis, based on carrier constraints (some devices which might technically support the FlashLite runtime may have its installation restricted by carriers who block user installation of apps).